# Grab the users screen-size/browser resolution

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, resolution, screen-resolution

How would I be able to grab the users screen-size or browser resolution (width only) when viewing my webpage, preferably with javaScript/jQuery or PHP and output the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` will get you the browser width.

`screen.width` will get you the monitor's resolution.

Here's an example: 
http://jsbin.com/abomod/1/edit

Comment: Fantastic Anthony, just what I was after!